# Побитовая операция

Tags: java, битовые-операции

Что происходит в данной строке?

```
((in.read() & 0xFF) << 8 | (in.read() & 0xFF)) //
```

В первый in.read() поступает 78, во-второй 132

Насколько я понимаю, смещение, но можно по-подробнее? Ну или же где про это почитать?

Comment: Cобираем число из двух байт, к каждому из которых применяем маску, которая переводит диапазон значений из (-128;127) в (0;255)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В данной строке из потока считывается двухбайтовое число, представленное в формате big endian («старшим байтом вперёд»).

Дело в том, что многобайтовые числа можно представить двумя способами:

1. Старшим байтом вперёд (big endian, он же сетевой порядок байтов). При нём `0xabcd` хранится как `AB CD`. Этот способ традиционно используют при передаче данных через интернет.
2. Младшим байтом вперёд (little endian, он же Intel-овский порядок байтов). При нём `0xabcd` хранится уже как `CD AB`. Этот способ является родным для большого количества процессоров (включая x86-совместимые, один из которых находится в вашем компьютере).

[image: порядок записи при big endian] [image: порядок записи при little endian]

*<sup>Расположение числа в памяти при различных порядках байтов. Источник: Википедия, [#1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Big-Endian.svg) , [#2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Little-Endian.svg)</sup>*

Могу предположить, что `in` — это сокет, и используемый вами прикладной протокол предписывает использовать big-endian. Как результат, при чтении многобайтных чисел напрямую получится мусор из-за несовпадения используемого и родного порядков байт. Соответственно, необходимо выполнить преобразование одним из двух способов:

1. Прочитать число целиком и переставить байты на месте;
2. Прочитать число побайтово, сразу же размещая очередной байт на подобающее ему место.

В вашем случае используется второй подход.

Замечу, что оба подхода сработают вне зависимости от родного порядка байт платформы, так как не важно, как будет храниться целевое число — важно, в какие разряды *универсального* (где старшие разряды всегда слева — `0xabcdefgh...`) представления вы их запишете — остальным озаботится процессор.

Answer (score 4):

Происходит чтение чего-то - `A= 0x......ab`  (байты A, количество разрядов зависит от определения функции `in.read()`)
Выделяется младший байт A и смещается влево (во второй байт) `0x00ab00`
Происходит новое чтение `C= 0x......cd`  (байты C)
Выделяется младший байт C и объединяется c предыдущим результатом.
Получается  `0x00abcd`
Это целочисленное значение, младшее слово которого содержит оба результата чтения.
Для приведённого примера чтения 78 и 132 получится 20100 (78*256+132)

Comment: Обновил вопрос, это ничего не меняет?

Comment: Нет, не меняет.